# Is it workable Properties.Settings.Default.Save() in ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel

Weirdly enough, but I can't to get it workable in ViewModel.

```
public class SmallWindow_ViewModel
{
public string My_property
        {
            get { return _my_property; }
            set { Set(ref _my_property, value); }
        }
        private string _my_property;


public void SmallWindow_unloaded()
        {

            Properties.Settings.Default.My_property_setting = My_property;

            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
}
```

If it is placed in Code Behind it works.

Comment: Who calls `SmallWindow_unloaded`?

Comment: Hi, Method works, I've checked. Command. ViewModel itself is working. I can't save property values when it is placed in ViewModel. The same code works perfectly in CB.

Comment: There must be more to it. Assuming your ViewModel is in the same assembly as your view, there is no reason the `Properties` would work in code-behind but not in a ViewModel method. That should be fine. I tried a very simple example to just make sure and it's working fine for me.

Comment: Can you show how your code is used? Are you sure `My_property` holds a value? Is the method actually invoked?

Comment: How do you know it's not working?